# Cannot resolve symbol 'SelectGameFragmentDirections'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

`public void onMomentClicked(Momentable event) { SelectGameFragmentDirections.ActionSelectGameFragmentToFantagFragment action = SelectGameFragmentDirections.actionSelectGameFragmentToFantagFragment(event); navController.navigate(action);}`

I am getting the following error's
->Cannot resolve symbol 'SelectGameFragmentDirections'.
->Cannot resolve method 'navigate(SelectGameFragmentDirections.ActionSelectGameFragmentToFantagFragment)'.

Comment: Have you created a navigation graph? If yes, then try rebuilding the project

Comment: Yes, I have created a navigation graph & I have rebuilt the project so many times but it is not working.